# Rails: How to connect to an old PostgreSQL (Your version of PostgreSQL (70417) is too old, please upgrade!)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

Trying to setup a connection to a remote PostgreSQL, I get the error:

> RuntimeError: Your version of PostgreSQL (70417) is too old, please upgrade!
>   from /Users/panayi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems
>   /activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters
>   /postgresql_adapter.rb:331:in `initialize'

I don't have access to the PostgreSQL, so there is no way to upgrade. I've tried to use an older `pg` gem:

```
# Gemfile
gem  'pg', '~> 0.9.0'
```

but then I get:

> LoadError: Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install
>   activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (can't activate pg (~> 0.11), already
>   activated pg-0.9.0. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.)

I'm stuck.

Comment: Try using older `activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (e.g. 0.9.0 too). You may have to uninstall your current `activerecord-postgresql-adapter` version.

Comment: @DracoAter Not working. Getting same LoadError msg above