# Monkey patch ActiveRecord's PostgreSQLAdapter method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, monkeypatching

Regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975918/rails-how-to-connect-to-an-old-postgresql-your-version-of-postgresql-70417-i), I'm trying to override the `postgresql_version` method defined in `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter` that returns the PostgreSQL version:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class PostgreSQLAdapter < AbstractAdapter

      protected
        # Returns the version of the connected PostgreSQL server.
        def postgresql_version
          80200
        end
    end
  end
end
```

But the patch isn't applied. I tried in a config/initializer and requiring it within a /lib file. Help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
# ensure ActiveRecord's version has been required already
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'

class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter 
protected
  def postgresql_version
    80200
  end
end
```

Your solution is failing because you can't add inheritance section while monkey-patching(i.e `PostgreSQLAdapter < AbstractAdapter`)

Comment: Tried this but I get: `TypeError: superclass mismatch for class PostgreSQLAdapter`

Comment: Ok requiring postgresql_adapter solves it: `require 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'`